# javascript array object in array object

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, object, nested-loops

I cant wrap my head around this one. can someone show me an example of a function that does this. I need a javascript function that will do this 
if all of array1s values matches array2s values return true if there is no/partial match return array1s values that did not match

```
array1 = [{name:'joe'},{name:'jill'},{name:'bob'}]
array2 = [{name:'joe'},{name:'jason'},{name:'sam'}]

match(array1, array2) 

//if fails returns [{name:'jill'}, {name:'bob'}]
//if success returns true
```

please help my brain hurts XD

Thanks

EDIT: Sorry for not saying this before the objects would have a few other property that wouldnt be the same. so a given object could look like

```
array1x = [{name:'joe', id:33},{name:'jill'},{name:'bob'}]
array2x = [{name:'joe', state:'fl'},{name:'jill'},{name:'bob'}]
```

i need to match just the name property within the object

Comment: Are you trying to match by position?  For example, if `array2` had `{name:'jill'}` in position 4, would that match fail, since it's in position 1 in `array1`?  Or would it succeed since it's in `array2` **somewhere**?

Comment: No i don't want the position to be a factor. thanks for your commit below by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) + [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) =

```
function match(arr1, arr2) {
    var notFound = arr1.filter(function(obj1) {
        return !arr2.some(function(obj2) {
            return obj2.name == obj1.name;
        });
    });

    return !notFound.length || notFound;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xvaD5/1/)

Comment: An **[abstraction](http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/wx6sF/)** of this technique keeps your nice algorithm but lifts the test of whether the two objects match into a callback function.

Comment: Worked perfectly! thank you XD and @ScottSauyet nice way to make it modular/reusable :-)

Comment: I think    return !array2.some(function(obj2) {  

Should be  return !arr2.some(function(obj2) {  

right?

Comment: @codenamejames You're right! I've fixed the typo :)

Comment: I would add another parameter to the match function with the name of the property name to check for to make it more usable:

    function match(arr1, arr2, id) {
    ...
    return obj2[id] == obj1[id];

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic example of such function:

```
function match(array1, array2) {
    var len = Math.max(array1.length, array2.length),
        result = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (JSON.stringify(array1[i]) !== JSON.stringify(array2[i])) {
            result.push(array1[i]);
        }
    }

    return result.length > 0 ? result : true;
}
```

It will compare the serialised elements as they go one-by-one considering index.